# Universal File System

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have an external hard drive I'd like to be able to mount read/write on windows/os x, and linux without a problem.

This drive up until now has been HFS+ and I had a problem with it being corrupt ever time i'd reboot ubuntu without shutting down every app using the drive and unmounting.

I'm going to format this drive, but i'd like to format it to a map and file system compatible with all 3 operating systems.

Is this exFAT?

Comment: exFAT is probably your best choice for overall compatibility:  https://www.howtogeek.com/235596/whats-the-difference-between-fat32-exfat-and-ntfs/

Comment: [File system compatible with all OSes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59585/44425), [Cross-Platform File System file sharing between MAC, WINDOWS, LINUX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/170407)

Answer (score 2):

- **FAT32 can be read by Linux, Windows and MacOS**. There are drawbacks with it, for example the maximum file size 4 GiB, and there is no journaling, but FAT32 is what I would recommend in this case.
- NTFS is a good alternative for sharing between Linux and Windows, but I don't think MacOS likes it.
- Linux file systems do not work in Windows. As pointed out by @muru, it is possible to install ext2fsd drivers into Windows and get decent read support for ext file systems (ext2, ext3, ext4).
- UDF, [Universal Disk Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format), might be an alternative, but it lacks important tools, for example repair tools.
- EXFAT is a Microsoft proprietary file system, and you must install extra tools in order to use it in Linux. I guess there is a problem with MacOS too.

Comment: ext* has decent read support on Windows with the ext2fsd drivers.

Comment: But you must install those drivers. If the OP can install ext2fsd drivers, where they want to use the external drive in Windows, yes, a linux `ext` file system is an alternative.

Comment: Sure, I pointed this out because you made a blanket statement that Linux filesystems do not work in Windows, but had no problems with saying exFAT will work if you install extra stuff.

Comment: @muru, I edited the answer to include your comment about ext2fsd drivers.

Comment: Doesn't sound like fat32 is the way to go for me if there is a 4gb file size limit.

Comment: If you backup the data in the drive at regular intervals, maybe you can accept a file system without repair tools, UDF: http://tanguy.ortolo.eu/blog/article93/usb-udf - My addition: Create a partition table and one partition (with gparted or mkusb) and then use udf in a partition: 
`sudo mkudffs -b 512 --media-type=hd --lvid=1 /dev/sdx1`

Comment: I actually don't back up at regular intervals, but  maybe i should considering. UDF is good for hard and softlinks as well?

Comment: Sounds like UDF is the better way to go.

Comment: I think you have to explore UDF on your own. I have tested that it works, but I have not used it beyond testing. I don't know about links, and I don't know how well the three different operating systems can manage special features (like links) in UDF.

Comment: am i in danger of data loss if i just go ext4 with extra drivers for read write on windows and os x?

Comment: The two crucial points are 1) that there might be problems to write from Windows and 2) how it works from MacOS. I have no own experience of reading and writing into a linux ext4 partition from MacOS. But I think it works from MacOS, - An alternative is two partitions (with different file systems). One of the file systems could be `FAT32`. You can write from all operating systems to `FAT32`. And one of the file systems could be `ext4`, and I think Windows and MacOS can read from `ext4`.